# Automatic password security test for WordPress

Tags: python, security, wordpress

I was bored the other day and wrote the following little script to attempt to find insecure passwords for WordPress blog owners so they could be notified of how easy it would be to crack their WP admin password.

I am mainly a Perl/PHP developer, so I want to make sure any Python work I do sticks to being Pythonic and not skewed by my main languages.

I wanted to know what techniques I can change and what code improvements should be used for the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
'''
Author: Matthew Harris <admin@mattharris.org>
Description: Provide interface to test security of Wordpress Admin Passwords and notify of weak passwords
Version: 1.0
Revision: 1
'''
import os
import re
import sys
import phpass
import MySQLdb

'''
Find a list of wordpress databases based of the wp_ table prefix
Currently set to search default value of cPanel boxes
'''
def find_wp_dbs():
    root_dir = '/var/lib/mysql'
    pattern = re.compile("^wp_")
    db_list = []
    print "[*] Gathering Wordpress Databases"
    if os.path.isdir(root_dir):
        for dir_name, sub_dir, file_list in os.walk(root_dir):
            found = 0
            for fname in file_list:
                if pattern.match(fname):
                    db_list.append(os.path.basename(dir_name))
                    break
        password = get_root_db_pass()
        print "[*] Gathering Wordpress Admin Users"
        print "[*] Running Password Comparisons Between Insecure Password List"
        all_errors = []
        all_insecure = []
        password_list = load_password_list()
        for db in db_list:
            data = get_admin_user(db, password)
            (errors, insecure) = test_passwords(data, password_list)
            if len(errors):
                all_errors.append(errors)
            if len(insecure):
                all_insecure.append(insecure)
        display_output(all_errors, all_insecure)
    else:
        print 'MySQL directory does not exist.' + "\n"

'''
Requires root to save on io operations on reading possibly thousands of
wp-config.php files to parse db data
'''
def get_root_db_pass():
    f = open('/root/.my.cnf')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    pattern = re.compile("^password=(.*)$")
    for line in lines:
        if pattern.match(line):
            match = pattern.match(line)
            return match.group(1)

'''
Function returns a data structure dict of list
'url' => [users]
'''
def get_admin_user(db, password):
    try:
        con = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'root', password, db)
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("""
            SELECT user_login,user_pass FROM wp_users 
            LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta ON wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id WHERE
            meta_key LIKE '%capabilities%' AND 
            meta_value LIKE '%admin%' 
            ORDER BY umeta_id
        """)
        users = cur.fetchall()
        cur.execute("""
            SELECT option_value FROM wp_options 
            WHERE option_name = 'siteurl';
        """)
        url = cur.fetchone()
        return {'url':url, 'users':users}
    except MySQLdb.Error, e:
        print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
    finally:
        if con:
            con.close()

'''
Load a precompiled list of commonly used insecure passwords
'''
def load_password_list():
    f = open('passwords.txt')
    passwords = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    return passwords

'''
Test the site admin against common easily crackable passwords
'''
def test_passwords(data, password_list):
    url = data['url'][0]
    users = data['users']
    user_count = len(users)
    total_md5 = 0
    errors = []
    insecure = []
    for u in users:
        username = u[0]
        password_hash = u[1]

        if len(password_hash) <= 32:
            '''
            Haven't written support yet for older versions and md5 conversion
            '''
            total_md5 += 1
        else:
            wp_hasher = phpass.PasswordHash(8, True)
            for p in password_list:
                p = p.strip()
                check = wp_hasher.check_password(p, password_hash)
                if check:
                    insecure.append("[!] Insecure password found for admin user %s:%s on %s" % (username, p, url))

    if total_md5 == user_count:
        errors.append("[!] All admin users require conversion from MD5 on %s" % url)

    return errors, insecure

'''
Display errors and insecure passwords
'''
def display_output(errors, insecure):
    print
    print "*******************************Insecure Passwords Found*****************************"
    for i in insecure:
        print "\n".join(i)
    print
    print "************************************Errors Found************************************"
    for e in errors:
        print "\n".join(e)

find_wp_dbs()
```

[GitHub](https://github.com/morissette/insecure-wp-admin-password-check)

Answer (score 2):

Python has a [style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) - you're compliant for the most part, but e.g.

> You should put a blank line between each group of imports.

```
import os
import re
import sys

import MySQLdb
import phpass
```

---

Python also has a [standard for docstrings](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) - they should be between the `def` and the first line inside the function, e.g.:

```
def display_output(errors, insecure):
    """Display errors and insecure passwords."""
    ...
```

You should also put your authorship information in a slightly different form, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/1523427/3001761.

---

You should use the "context manager" `with` for e.g. file handling, which makes the scope of the open file clearer and removes the need to explicitly `close` it:

```
with open('passwords.txt') as f:
    passwords = f.readlines()
return passwords
```

`MySQLdb` may also support this usage, removing the need for the over-long `try`.

---

An empty sequence (e.g. `[]`, `''`) evaluates `False`-y, so you can write:

```
if errors:
```

rather than

```
if len(errors):
```

---

You can use unpacking to simplify:

```
for u in users:
    username = u[0]
    password_hash = u[1]
```

to:

```
for username, password_hash in users:
```

---

I would probably shorten e.g.:

```
check = wp_hasher.check_password(p, password_hash)
if check:
```

to:

```
if wp_hasher.check_password(p, password_hash):
```

which removes the need for the temporary name.

---

```
found = 0
```

This is never used, and should be removed.

---

It is typical to add a guard to your script, so that you can later `import` functionality from it without running anything:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    find_wp_dbs()
```